# UILabel not showing text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, uilabel

I have a UILabel

```
IBOutlet UILabel *lblMissionLevel;
[lblMissionLevel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -55 , 177.0, 43.0)];

UIView *view= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11.0, 55.0, 480, 500)];
[view addSubview:lblMissionLevel];
```

and I'm setting the text using

```
lblMissionLevel.text = @"My String";
```

My issue is, most of the time it shows the correct text but at sometimes it shows simply

```
Label
```

I can't trace the issue since it is not consistent.

Please help. If anyone requires further clarification please do ask..

Comment: With *this* code, your label will always show up with "My String". Maybe you should give us some "real life" code :)

Comment: I think the default text for uilabels is "Label" which you can see in your nib, if you have created it in nib. I guess if its text setting condition is not met, it shows this default text "Label" ?

Comment: When I saw your question at first I thought you didn't connected the outlet to the file owner or something, but as you said `most of the time it shows the correct text` I can't really say what's the problem unless I see more code.

Comment: @fardjad I've added more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is intermittent then the likely cause is the low memory warning, this will cause any non-active view to unload. If you are not handling the re-loading of this view you will see the default Label caption once the view becomes active again (it will load but the initialisation you do with label captions etc is probably not being called).

I had the same thing until I noticed the memory warning level 1 and then it would occur. I added code to reload the view correctly (setting up all the UI controls captions correctly) and it was all good!

Comment: Thanks buddy...I was getting a memory warning level 2. After I resolved it everything is working flawless....

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes had that issue, your best to apply (in your class header)

`@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *lblMissionLevel;`

and then make sure you call `self.` before `lblMissionLevel.text = @"My String";`

Remember to synthesize after stating class implementation

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the line above, most likely your ivar isn't being set from your nib

```
    NSAssert(lblMissionLevel, @"lblMissionLevel is nil");
```

Then have a read up on how to use NSAssert really handy

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of setting the negative value for your `UILabel`.

```
[lblMissionLevel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -55 , 177.0, 43.0)];
```

Try to print the content of lblMissionLevel.text after setting the string value.

```
lblMissionLevel.text = @"My String";
NSLog(@"My Label Text %@", lblMissionLevel.text);
```

Also check the drawing location of `UILabel`.